# Reading or accessing Custom Configuration extension in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

I have build an custom configuration ( provider and services ) based on the below article.
https://medium.com/@dneimke/custom-configuration-in-net-core-2-193ff6f02046

Now when want to access the custom added provider from the `IConfiguration` while using DI.

My `Configuration` in the startup looks like

[image]

It shows it has 6 providers and the 5th index marked was my custom configuration.

**How could i access the custom configuration added by me  ( 5th index) when injecting `IConfiguration` in my controllers ?**

[image]

Need to get the value of **connection and connectionsettings** from the custom configuration

TIA

Comment: How do you set connection and connectionsettings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get all configuration Providers from `IConfigurationRoot.Providers`,for example

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration = null;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var configurationRoot = _configuration as IConfigurationRoot;

        var provider = (DbProvider)configurationRoot.Providers.Last();

       // Or get specific provider using index as below comment has shown
       // var list = configurationRoot.Providers.ToList();
       // var provider = (DbProvider)list[5];

        var connectionSettings = provider.connectionSettings;

        return View();
    }
}
```